# ResourceInitializationError: failed to validate logger args: : signal: killed

Tags: aws-fargate

Suddenly getting the message " ResourceInitializationError: failed to validate logger args: : signal: killed" while starting AWS ECS Fargate Service. Same service was running fine couple of days back.

Following is log driver configurations in related aws task:

Log Configuration
**Log driver: awslogs**
**Key                       Value**
**awslogs-group**           /ecs/analytics
**awslogs-region**          us-east-1
**awslogs-stream-prefix**   ecs

Any idea or help?

Comment: This questions is not appropriate for Stackoverflow - it is not a programming related question.  You might try asking on Server Fault (serverfault.com)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm having the exact same issue but haven't found any solution. It also seems like this post is the only one mentioning the issue.

Answer (score 42):

I finally found the root cause:

The error appears if the fargate service is not able to connect to the CloudWatch api endpoint.
This might happen if you have fargate running in a private subnet without internet access.
You could either add the CloudWatch log Endpoint to your private subnet or add internet connectivity

Comment: For people going for the endpoint way, the endpoint service to use is `com.amazonaws.eu-west-1.logs` .
Complete list of endpoint here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-service-information.html

Comment: I would like to comment that I was only able to get over this error by *deleting* an existing log endpoint (in my case `com.amazonaws.use-ease-1.logs` service from my vpc. After that the error went away.

Comment: I recently added the VPC Endpoint for cloudwatch logs to my setup and this now prevents my existing ECS cluster from posting to cloudwatch logs when they have internet access.

Comment: @Luke when you add a private endpoint to your VPC it will override the DNS entries for that service. You'll need to make sure all ECS instances can reach the private endpoint

Comment: Thanks @davidgiga1993, I have added an answer that works to this question

Answer (score 9):

I recently spent hours on this same issue. It turns out that the log group and stream prefix specified in my container definition didn't exist.

It would be wonderful if AWS could provide helpful error messages...

Comment: Thanks @Drakee510! In addition to this, I also had to add the "CloudWatchLogsFullAccess" policy to the Execution Role. Perhaps there is a better way, but I haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 6):

Came across this issue today. The issue was that the log group I specified didn't exist yet. If you don't want to manually create it, make sure to add the `awslogs-create-group` and set it to `"true"`. You'll have to grant your ECS Task Execution role a `logs:CreateLogGroup` permission as well.

```
  "logConfiguration": {
    "logDriver": "awslogs",
    "secretOptions": null,
    "options": {
      "awslogs-create-group": "true",
      "awslogs-group": "/ecs/app",
      "awslogs-region": "ap-southeast-2",
      "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
    }
  }
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html

Comment: Right, but nobody seems to know how to specify the `logs:CreateLogGroup` permission inline in the CloudFormation template. See my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/75455047 . Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I just experienced this. I have ECS Fargate running and I've just added a VPC endpoint for Cloudwatch Logs `com.amazonaws.REGION.logs` in my account. When I added the VPC endpoint my logs stopped appearing.

In order to remedy this without deleting the VPC endpoint again, for my setup with Fargate running with internet access I had to ensure that:

1. My ECS service had a security group rule that to allows HTTPS traffic outbound

   ```
   {
      type: egress
      port_to: 443   
      port_from: 443
      protocol: TCP
   }
   ```
2. That my new VPC Endpoint had a security group rule to allow HTTPS traffic inbound from my ECS security group

   ```
   {
      type: ingress
      port_to: 443   
      port_from: 443
      protocol: TCP
      source_security_group_id: [Your ECS SECURITY GROUP ID]
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error, checked my NAT and IG, and all is good. And I found the endpoint interface also was set up as com.amazonaws.use-ease-1.logs
Nothing seems to need to change. Finally, I deleted the interface endpoint and the error went away.
But I am still confusing what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Adding CloudWatchLogsFullAccess policy to ECS task execution role solved my problem (suggested by @redgeoff )